# How to pass a list of data from one partial view to another partial view, when both partial views are contained in a same parent view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 partial views, `HeadphonesFilters` and `HeadphonesList` which are both contained inside an `Index` view which is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="alert alert-primary p-2">Headphones</h3>
        <div class="col-4">
            @Html.Partial("HeadphonesFilters", new { minPrice=0,maxPrice=0})
        </div>
        <div class="col-8" id="headphones-list">
            @Html.Partial("HeadphonesList")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The `HeadphonesList` partial view accepts a list of `Headphone` type objects and displays them. The `HeadphonesFilters` partial view should return the list of filtered headphones to the `HeadphonesList` partial view.

All the three views are accessing the same `HeadphonesController`.

The `HeadphonesFilter`  partial view uses a `Filter` method which is as follows:

```
public PartialViewResult Filter(int minPrice, int maxPrice)
{
    var list = service.GetHeadphones()
                      .Where(x => x.SKU.SKUPrice >= minPrice && 
                                  x.SKU.SKUPrice <= maxPrice)
                      .ToList();
    return PartialView("HeadphonesList", list);
}
```

This filter method returns the filtered headphones in a separate page, whereas I want this list to go to the `HeadphonesList` partial view and that view should be updated with the new list.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The `Filter` method can be called through ajax (for example jQuery ajax). On success it can re-render the ProductList partial view. In your case the result received from the server is the full html of the partial view ant this can be rendered inside a parent div element . This can be the parent div of the original ProductList partial view, so it appears like a reload. (one example https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use Ajax to get the data from controller to view without refreshing the whole page